# I have a query and I want to execute this query using lambda invocation?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda, react-fullstack

I have a task where I have to fetch the details from mysql and have to log the data in xlsx file but the problem is I have more than 140 columns in mysql table and also more than 150000 records on an average for a month. I am not able to download all the data for one month. I am using node js and aws for lambda invocation.

```
SELECT filterTable.jobSequenceNumber, sntl_invoice_details_import_Ref.invoiceSlNo AS invoiceSequenceNumber, sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.itemSlNo AS itemSequenceNumber, sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.itemSlNo AS "Item Sno", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.partCode AS "Part Code", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.description AS "Description", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.concatDescription AS "Concat Description", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.hsn AS "HSN", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.qty AS "Qty", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.uom AS "UOM", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.cusQty AS "Cus Qty", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.cusUom AS "Cus UOM", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.unitPrice AS "Unit Price", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.amount AS "Amount", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.specificQty1 AS "Specific Qty 1", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.uom1 AS "UOM1", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.uom2 AS "UOM2", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.generalDescription AS "Generic Description", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.specificQty2 AS "Specific Qty 2", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerName AS "Manufacturer Name", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerType AS "Manufacturer Type", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerCode AS "Manufacturer Code", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerAddress1 AS "Manufacturer Address1", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerAddress2 AS "Manufacturer Address2", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerCity AS "Manufacturer City", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerSubDivision AS "Manufacturer Sub Division", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerPin AS "Manufacturer Pin", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.manufacturerCountry AS "Manufacturer Country", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.model AS "Model", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.endUse AS "End Use", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.brand AS "Brand", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.countryOfOrigin AS "Country Of Origin", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.sourceCountry AS "Source Country", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.transitCountry AS "Transit Country", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.bcdNtfnNo AS "BCD Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.bcdNtfnSlNo AS "BCD Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.customsAdditionalDutyNtfnNo AS "Customs Additional Duty Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.customsAdditionalDutyNtfnSlNo AS "Customs Additional Duty Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.chCessNtfnNo AS "Health Cess Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.chCessNtfnSlNo AS "Health Cess Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.caidcNtfnNo AS "CAIDC Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.caidcNtfnSlNo AS "CAIDC Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.swsNtfnNo AS "SWS Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.swsNtfnSlNo AS "SWS Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.cusEduCessNtfnNo AS "Cus.Edu. Cess Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.cusEduCessNtfnSlNo AS "Cus.Edu. Cess Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.nccdNtfnNo AS "NCCD Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.nccdNtfnSlNo AS "NCCD Notification Sr.No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.saptaNtfnNo AS "SAPTA Notification No.", sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.saptaNtfnSlNo AS "SAPTA Notification Sr.No." FROM ((SELECT filterJobRefNo, row_number() over() as jobSequenceNumber FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sntl_job_details_import_filter.id as filterJobRefNo FROM (SELECT * FROM sntl_job_details_import WHERE  isActiveJob="1" AND tenant_id="8e95996f-4de1-45b7-9e5d-d327483f239a" AND DATE(`jobCreationDate`) BETWEEN '2023-03-20' AND '2023-03-21' order by create_Date_Time desc) sntl_job_details_import_filter ) table1) filterTable INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM sntl_invoice_details_import WHERE isActiveInvoice=1) sntl_invoice_details_import_Ref ON sntl_invoice_details_import_Ref.jobRefNo=filterTable.filterJobRefNo INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM sntl_lineItem_import WHERE activeLineItem=1) sntl_lineItem_import_Ref ON sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.jobRefNo=filterTable.filterJobRefNo AND sntl_lineItem_import_Ref.invoiceRefNo=sntl_invoice_details_import_Ref.invoiceCreationDate) ORDER BY jobSequenceNumber, invoiceSequenceNumber, itemSequenceNumber;
```

```
const fs = require("fs");
const xlsx = require("xlsx");

module.exports.createReportFileS3 = async (report,sqlRes) => {
    try {
      let responseOutput = []

      if(report.template?.sheetType==="multiple"){
        sqlRes.forEach(item => {
          if( Array.isArray(item)){
            responseOutput = [...responseOutput, item]
          }
        })
        console.log(responseOutput)
        fs.writeFileSync("responseOutput.json",JSON.stringify(responseOutput));
        const newWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
        for(const [index, column] of responseOutput.entries()){
          const newWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(column);
          xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB, newWS, `${report.tableLabelName[index]}`);  
        }

        xlsx.writeFile(newWB, `/tmp/${report.template.id}.xlsx`);  //construct xlsx file with fetched data in local
      }else{
        console.log('report..',report);
        let responseOutput = []
        sqlRes.forEach(item => {
          if( Array.isArray(item)){
            responseOutput = [...item]
          }
        })
        const newWB = xlsx.utils.book_new();
        const newWS = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(responseOutput);
        xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB, newWS, "USERS_LIST");
        xlsx.writeFile(newWB, `/tmp/${report.template.id}.xlsx`);  //construct xlsx file with fetched data in local
      }
        const reportCreationDate = report.reportCreationDate//Date.now() 
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`/tmp/${report.template.id}.xlsx`) // a ReadStream
        let params = { 
                Bucket: config.S3_BUCKET.REPORTS_BUCKET_NAME,  //S3 bucket name
                Key: `sntl_reports/${report.template.id}/${report.template.templateName}${reportCreationDate}.xlsx`, //file storage path and name
                Body: readStream,
                ACL:"public-read", //acess control list
                ContentType:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' 
            };    
        
        console.log(params)
        const command = new PutObjectCommand(params)
        const data = await client.send(command);
        console.log("data",data);
        fs.unlink(`/tmp/${report.template.id}.xlsx`, (err) => { //delete xlsx file in local
          if (err){
            throw err;
            console.log("error delete file");
          }
        });
        return data
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("error in upload xlsx file in s3 bucket", error, report, sqlRes);
    } 
}
```

when I tried to pass the query in lambda its giving as timeout exception even I increased AWS lambda time to max limit.

Comment: Lambda can be executed for max 15 minutes, then it will time-out. You may have to divide the load between multiple Lambda function calls. You can have a dynamic `LIMIT` clause in your query to process say 10000 records only per Lambda. Trigger the same Lambda multiple times with different OFFSET (set as env variable or something) and export data in separate files per batch/page.  And then combine the result into a single file using a separate Lambda. Or create Step Functions to control Lambda calls till the time all the records are processed.

Comment: Please add `aws-lambda` tag also in the question.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to fetch data from a MySQL table with a complex SQL query having more than 140 columns and 150000 records on an average for a month. Also, you want to log this data into an xlsx file using Node.js and AWS Lambda. However, you are facing issues while downloading all the data for one month.

Comment: To handle such a large amount of data, you can implement pagination in your SQL query to fetch the data in smaller chunks. You can limit the number of records per page and use the OFFSET clause to skip the already fetched records. This way, you can fetch the data in smaller chunks and log it into an xlsx file using the Node.js xlsx library.

Comment: Lambda is probably not the right tool for the job

Comment: can you please elaborate that how can I implement dynamic pagination. because I don't know exactly how much data will be there its vary each month.